# .exe with several possible entries

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, program-entry-point

I have a VB.NET program that, in "normal use" shows a welcome form and does whatever it does, but that should be also callable from a batch in a mode where the form is bypassed.
I tried:

```
Sub Main(s As String)
    MainSub(False)
End Sub
Sub Main()
    MainSub(True)
End Sub
Sub MainSub(ShowTheForm As Boolean)
    'whatever
end sub
```

and the batch:

```
MyProgram.exe "YES"
```

The form shows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the arguments sent from command line you need to use the following and then use appropriately. The "YES" parameter you are sending is string, so when you retrieve it property make sure you convert it to boolean `CBool(arg)`

```
If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs.Length > 1 Then
        ' Loop and find each argument
        For Each arg In Environment.GetCommandLineArgs

            If arg.ToString = "yes" Then 
                 'Do stuff here
             End If
        Next
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great!